# Harmonic Analysis of Commendatore Scene

Tags: theory, mozart, opera

Where can I find a good old fashioned roman numeral analysis of the Commendatore scene from Don Giovanni?

I know a fair amount of classical music theory (well, enough to be dangerous) and I've always wondered what is going on harmonically in this piece. It sounds like Mozart is doing a bunch of super cool stuff with modes and I'd love to see it all explained somewhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Weird, I thought the point of Harmony class was to teach you how to create your own Roman numeral analysis of any tonal music (and some atonal music) you want.

Comment: @Dekkadeci I don't understand your comment. Was there some since-deleted comment you were responding to?

Comment: @Aaron is seems perfectly clear to me: Dekkadeci is suggesting that John C. use his knowledge of music theory to produce the analysis he's asking for in this question.  Obviously there are various ways of reconciling the apparent contradictions here, but I would tend to take Dekkadeci's side, especially if an existing analysis of the scene isn't readily available online. I'm almost motivated to do my own analysis for an answer but don't have time. John C. is more likely to get a useful response by presenting at least a partial analysis and asking for help with the problem spots.

Comment: Welcome! Please check out [the topics that are covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Although one of them is "technical analysis of a specific, complete work, or well defined section thereof," one of the things that's not covered is requests for outside resources. In other words, a question like "Here's what I've got so far but I can't figure out this bit" (with images of the music) would be covered, but any kind of "help me find ___" question isn't. But Don G has been talked about and analyzed for a long time now, and there's definitely material out there!

Comment: (Meanwhile, even though this has been closed, feel free to edit it into a more substantial question and it can be reopened.)

Comment: @phoog I see. So you’re saying the response was simply condescending.